# TitledBorder problem with Substance UI and custom JComponent

Tags: java, swing, border, jcomponent, substance

I'm using `BorderFactory` to create a titled border with a Substance UI themed Swing user interface, and I'm coming across the exception shown below. I tried with `LineBorder` and it works perfectly, but it appears that Substance UI is interfering somehow with `TitledBorder`. The border drawing is done in `paintComponent` via:

```
if (getBorder() != null) {
   getBorder().paintBorder(this, g, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
}
```

which itself may be incorrect. My question is essentially how to get `TitledBorder` working without creating a parent `JPanel` and setting it on that instead, which seems like a bit of a cop-out.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.pushingpixels.lafwidget.utils.RenderingUtils.desktopHints(RenderingUtils.java:113)
    at org.pushingpixels.lafwidget.utils.RenderingUtils.installDesktopHints(RenderingUtils.java:85)
    at org.pushingpixels.substance.internal.utils.border.SubstanceEtchedBorder.paintBorder(SubstanceEtchedBorder.java:132)
    at javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.paintBorder(TitledBorder.java:330)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintBorder(JComponent.java:947)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1055)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)
    at javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(JLayeredPane.java:585)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5213)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(RepaintManager.java:1493)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1424)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1217)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1040)
    at java.awt.GraphicsCallback$PaintCallback.run(GraphicsCallback.java:39)
    at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runOneComponent(SunGraphicsCallback.java:78)
    at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runComponents(SunGraphicsCallback.java:115)
    at java.awt.Container.paint(Container.java:1951)
    at java.awt.Window.paint(Window.java:3814)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:792)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:739)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:688)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$700(RepaintManager.java:59)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1632)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:660)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What component are you trying to add the border to? Does this happen for all components?  You say it doesn't happen with `JPanel`s...

Comment: You might get more luck reporting this directly to the Substance team so they can investigate, or at least suggest a workaround. I'm assuming that the problem goes away if you use the default LaF.

Comment: did you manage to sort this out? Do you have any progress on it? Maybe could you also provide an SSCCE for the issue? I would like to play with it.

Comment: I sorted it out by wrapping the component up in a panel, and then giving a border to that panel :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug deep in the bowels of laf-widget.  It currently assumes that every Graphics object has a GraphicsConfiguration and a GraphicsDevice associated with it.  I have a fork of substance called [insubstantial](https://github.com/insubstantial/insubstantial/) that [has a fix](https://github.com/Insubstantial/insubstantial/issues/13) for this.

The maven coordinates for the current snapshot this is fixed in are com.github.insubstantial:substance:6.3-SNAPSHOT and the snapshot repository is at https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/.  I anticipate releasing the 6.3 train at or around the end of June.

Comment: Sure :) I was thinking of switching over to Insubstantial too, by the way.